# Lint fails with Unresolved reference: it

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

Android project has 2 modules:

- library
- sample

Both are in Kotlin. Sample should ignore lint checks:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
    }
}
```

But when `./gradlew lint` is called there is set of errors like this:

```
Unresolved reference: it
```

`it` is kotlin lambda value like:

```kotlin
object.call({
  it.anotherCall()
})
```

Why `sample` is not ignored by lint? And why `it` is even a problem? Looks like lint try to analyze java code.

Answer (score 0):

Really dumb problem, the `sample` project was using debug variant, but not release. So lint just couldn't resolve library dependencies.

```
debugImplementation project(':library')
```

Comment: I have same problem ... Is there any workaround ?